# Creating multiple threads in C: write pid, tid and return integer

Tags: c, multithreading, pid

I must do this:

*Write a program whose main thread creates 3 other threads. Each ot these threads (different from the main thread) shall write its pid and tid and terminate returning an integer number between 1 and 3 and different from the value returned by the other threads. The main thread shall print in the standard out its pid and the value returned by each of the other threads.*

I think I'm doing it right, except that I don't understand how should I *return the integer numbers between 1 and 3*

I've the following code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#define DEBUG 0

// int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr, void *(*start_routine)(void*), void *arg);

// int pthread_join(pthread_t, void **value_ptr);

void *printID(void *arg){

    int i;

    unsigned long tid;
    tid = *((unsigned long *) arg);           

    printf("Thread tid: %lu Thread pid: %d \n", tid, getpid());

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    pthread_t id1, id2, id3;

    pthread_create(&id1, NULL, printID, &id1);

    pthread_create(&id2, NULL, printID, &id2);

    pthread_create(&id3, NULL, printID, &id3);

    pthread_join(id1, NULL);

    pthread_join(id2, NULL);

    pthread_join(id3, NULL);

    printf("Main thread pid: %d\n", getpid());

    sleep(1);

}
```

Comment: The last argument in [pthread_create(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_create) is for arguments. So if you want all of them to return different values, you can send them different arguments. sending pthread_t is redundant since you can get it via [pthread_self(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_self)

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: @holgac what do you mean with pthread_create(3)?

Comment: @jeff , no it's not a homework, it's a problem I'm trying to solve to practice for the tests I will have.

Comment: I meant the `pthread_create` function. parentheses and section nunber are often used to represent the function. See [here](http://superuser.com/questions/297702/what-do-the-parentheses-and-number-after-a-unix-command-or-c-function-mean) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Since threads in c can return void*. you can allocate a space for the int you want to return, read it from the main, but don’t forget to free it.